# Setting the correct raster no data value with gdal

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate

I am trying to split a multi-band raster using gdal, and in the process set the nodata value to 0 (currently it is -9999). The way I thought to do this was as follows:

```
gdal_translate -b 1 -a_nodata 0 scr_ds.tif dst_ds.tif
```

I think this does set the nodata value to 0, but doesn't update the -9999 values to 0. So I tried to use gdalwarp to first convert all -9999 values to 0. However this returns [1] - which I believe means it failed. The gdalwarp line of code I used was:

```
gdalwarp -dstnodata 0 src_ds.tif dst_ds.tif
```

Comment: Did you try including -srcnodata -9999 in your call to gdalwarp? Also, you need to see the error message so you know what the problem is. How are you calling gdalwarp? From the command line? Subprocess python call? etc.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the delay. It works. Thank you very much